# Django Template does not exist error, although it shows 'file exists'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am not able to render any html pages in Django 1.7. My 'index.html' is in          '`project/seatalloc/templates/index.html`'  and my view.py in `project/seatalloc/views.py` looks like:

```
 def index(request):
       return render(request, 'index.html', dirs=('templates',))
```

project/project/settings.py has templates dirs set:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Users/Palak/Desktop/academics/sem3/cs251/lab11/project/seatalloc/templates',

)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^seatalloc/', include('seatalloc.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

[image: Template loader]

I have tried to follow the documentation strictly, yet can't figure out if Django detects the file, why am I getting TemplateDoesNotExist at /seatalloc/ error. I am new to Django, could someone please help.

Comment: Looks like `setalloc` is an app. You don't actually need to tell `template_dirs` about it's templates, as you can see below the line you highlighted, it's already found by the app directories loader. `template_dirs` is for non-app templates, usually located in the project root, not in an app.

Comment: I figured out the problem: the url I was providing earlier was url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), I changed it  to url(r'^index$', views.index, name='index'), this + moving the templates_dir to project root solved it. Thanks all for helping

Answer (score 32):

If - as in your case - you get a TemplateDoesNotExist error and the debug page states "File exists" next to the template in question this usually (always?) means this template refers to another template that can't be found.

In your case, index.html contains a statement (`{% extends %}, {% include %}, ...` ) referring to another template Django cannot find. Unfortunately, as of Django 1.8.3, the debug page always names the base template, not the one Django can't find.

Comment: +1, this helped me. "TemplateDoesNotExist error" was on index.html which existed but was extended by base.html which had include for a missing template.  Interesting note, the "TemplateDoesNotExist error" didn't appear until after I logged into Admin and tried to view site because the missing include was login related.

Comment: This was the issue! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),
)
```

Comment: where should I define PROJECT_ROOT. defining it in settings.py gives me invalid syntax

Comment: Deprecated since 1.8: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs

Comment: @Wtower: You are right, it's deprecated, wasted half an hour trying to get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

First of all don't use static path (fixed path) in template dirs in settings.py, use:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      BASE_DIR +'/Templates',


  )
```

And template directory should be in project directory i.e in which manage.py file exists.

And in view.py use `render_to_response` instead of just `render`.

```
return  render_to_response("index.html")
```

Comment: thanks! actually I removed the entire TEMPLATE_DIRS (..) code from my settings.py. The trouble was with the path of template directory.After putting it in project dir, things worked

Comment: Hey, what you suggested works for the index.html page, eg:http://127.0.0.1:8000/seatalloc/ but for any other page http://127.0.0.1:8000/seatalloc/index or http://127.0.0.1:8000/seatalloc/detail it displays the 404 error. All the .html files are in the same directory

Comment: -1 for recommending the one older render_to_response o over the newer render.