# Django doesn't load a template correctly, even though it seems to have found it

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm attempting to create a central directory for all of my html templates. The path is a directory up from my settings.py file, so it is at ../templates/index.html relative to the settings directory.

I have the following specified for templates settings in `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates')
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

The view in views.py is almost the same as the default:

```
def home(request):

    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'home page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )
```

After I start the devserver and try to go to the main page, I get the following error, which is very confusing:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
index.html
...
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\source\project\web_page\templates\index.html (File exists)
```

EDIT: In case it matters, here's the url for that page (again, almost the same as the default):

```
...
url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name = 'home'),
...
```

How could it be that Django is finding the template, but is not loading it?

Comment: Could `index.html` refer to a template that doesn't exist?

Comment: The file is definitely at C:\source\project\web_page\templates\index.html in my filesystem.

Comment: I wasn't clear, I meant that the contents of `index.html` might refer to a template that does not exist. For example, maybe it contains `{% extends 'base.html' %}`, but `base.html` does not exist.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to use `RequestContext` when using `render`. Your view can simplify to `return render(request, 'index.html, {'title': 'home page', ... })`.

Comment: I think you're onto something with the contents of index.html causing problems. I emptied the html text of the file and it loaded. Trying to remove chunks of the page now to find the problem part.

Comment: replace index.html with templates/index.html
or try uncommenting this Line in settings.py file 
#'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

Comment: @Alasdair It was as you said; there was a problem in a layout.html file that I was including in the page (a url problem with another part of the site). Still, the original error message is confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib I don't think `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` is the problem here, and it would be better to remove `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` from settings completely. In Django 1.8, you should use the [`loaders`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) parameter in `OPTIONS` instead, and there is also an `APP_DIRS` option to enable/disable loading templates from your apps' template directories.

Comment: Glad you fixed the problem. Yes, you're right, it's a confusing error message, and you're not the first person to be caught out (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604294/django-template-does-not-exist-error-although-it-shows-file-exists) for example).